# uwsgi python3 plugin doesn't work

Tags: plugins, python-3.x, compilation, uwsgi, python-3.3

i compiled uwsgi with make and it's successfully done,and now i decide to run my django1.5 site with python3.3 . i've checked for the doc (http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Guide4Packagers) and set up python3.3 development headers through apt-get and then compile the plugin by:

> python3.3 uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python package python33

then it says:

```
using profile: buildconf/package.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/include', '/usr/local/include','/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed', '/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/include']
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin plugins/python ***
[i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] /usr/lib/uwsgi/python33_plugin.so
*** python33 plugin built and available in /usr/lib/uwsgi/python33_plugin.so ***
```

it seems all is well done and i do find python33_plugin.so in that dir.
nginx is running and is ok,now my uwsgi ini file is like this:

```
[uwsgi]  
socket=0.0.0.0:8000 
listen=20
master=true
pidfile=/usr/local/nginx/uwsgi.pid
processes=2
plugins=python33
module=django_wsgi
pythonpath=
profiler=true
memory-report=true
enable-threads=true
logdate=true
limit-as=6048
```

and when i run "sudo ./uwsgi uwsgi.ini",

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
open("./python33_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3347]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python33_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
```

it doesn't find the .so file.anyway then i copy the .so file to the uwsgi dir,and run again,

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - *** Starting uWSGI 1.9.8 (32bit) on [Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013] ***
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - compiled with version: 4.7.3 on 28 April 2013 21:25:27
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - os: Linux-3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - nodename: bill-Rev-1-0
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - machine: i686
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - clock source: unix
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - pcre jit disabled
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - detected number of CPU cores: 4
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - current working directory: /media/bill/cloud/cloud/program/kkblog/kkblog
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - writing pidfile to /usr/local/nginx/uwsgi.pid
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - your processes number limit is 31552
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - limiting address space of processes...
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - your process address space limit is 2046820352 bytes (1952 MB)
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000 fd 3
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:35:44)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x973e2d0
Sun Apr 28 22:54:40 2013 - python threads support enabled
```

i'm using ubuntu 13.04 and python2.7 and python3.3 are preinstalled.

I SET THE PYTHON33 PLUGIN BUT UWSGI STILL LAUNCHES PYTHON2.7 ,why?

anybody who ever met this problem? and by the way i don't like to setup uwsgi and plugins through apt-get,because it won't work at any PaaS.

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have built a monolithic uWSGI binary with python 2.7 embedded so a plugin cannot overwrite  that area of memory. You can build a simple monolithic python3 binary using:

```
python3 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

or using pip for python3

Otherwise you can build a fully modular system with:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --build core
python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python core python27
python3 uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/python core python33
```

Comment: Hi @roberto. Where can I find the uwsgiconfig.py? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aldesabido It works a little different nowadays. See [the official docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary).

Comment: Now, from the same directory, we start building Python plugins:
what's uwsgi?   could you tell in detail? --build-plugin
PYTHON=python3.4 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python34"
PYTHON=python2.7 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python27"
PYTHON=python2.6 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python26"